# Typescript can't infer a generic type parameter from function arguments

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```js
type Collection<T = any> = T[]

type CollectionGetter = () => Collection

function collectionProcessor(getter: CollectionGetter) {
  const res = getter();
  // some processing...
  // return collection of the same type
  return res;
}

// ---

interface Item {
  id: number;
}

const myGetter = () => {
  return [
    {
      id: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2
    },
    {
      id: 3
    }
  ] as Collection<Item>
}

const result = collectionProcessor(myGetter);
// typeof result = Collection<any>
// expected: Collection<Item>
console.log(result);
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=35&ssc=21&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwRAxsAlnAdgHgCpQC8UAhliAHxFR4DaAugFCOiSyLJqZYDiEwwCACdqACgCURKvCSoM2ZgDMArli7YoKDnO4AFIXBQQAzsbhDRAc36ChALnaz1vG8MkBvRlE3ZjwKEIm1NYCwhIA3F5QAPTRUGYAttBgBkam6FiWAHQ5UbEB-MpCWD5O8iVwilDAABbQxiRJ1eAQUYHARSWBxpEAvsz5ALTDzBm2iiRGUACSgglQnt7oACYOWMoJAEbCfcxaWH5QCSB8oSLEElILbYXFULRR3oveLysOAIyPUL0ANF-PLygbygACYvr9-l8lqsoABmcFReikYyOTjlHCzCAJCiMfqMfaHbrKBD%20YhaMp6VImMwWY6nWziSL5VgQSoFYzE0monTYHBkSiMfIQAAekDQEBhMjR3AxcxxBMQECyCDgllERJJjMYQA)

Typescript can't infer the `Collection<T>` type parameter from the argument passed to `collectionProcessor`.

What is the right way to type this example?

I know I can type the processor like this `function collectionProcessor<R>(getter: CollectionGetter): Collection<R>` and pass the type explicitly `collectionProcessor<Item>(myGetter)`, but that would not be very convenient as the argument is passed down from higher levels of abstraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing some generics to complete the chain.

```
type CollectionGetter<T> = () => Collection<T>
```

By omitting `<T>` here, you were infering only `any`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwRAxsAlnAdgHgCpQC8UAhliAHxFR4DaAugFCOiSyLJqZYDiEwwCACd8VYgAoAlESrwkqDNlHMAZgFcsXbFBQcF3AApC4KCAGczcEXgriA5v0FCAXO3lbej4aOkBvRlA62GbAUELm1A4CwlIA3AFQAPSJUJYAttBgxqYW6Fh2AHRFCclh-GpCWEHuilVwKlDAABbQZiQZjeAQCeHAFVXhZvEAvsylALSTzHlOKiSmUACSgmlQ-oHoACauWGppAEbCI8y6WCFQaSB80ULUUjJrPeWVULQJgeuBX1uuAIzvUGGABoAZ8vlAflAAEwA4GggEbbZQADMsIS9FIZjcnFqOGWEDSFEYo0Yp3OgzUCFCxF0NUM2XMliE4ku1ycknipVYEHqZTMlOp2P0SjIlEYpQgAA9IGgIEi5DjuHiVkSyYgIAUEHA7OIKVSOYwgA)